# Contour Integration cauchy integration formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

If I have the integrand

> $$\frac{e{^z}^2}{(2z+i)(z+3i)^2}$$

for the circles with centre $a$ radius $2$.

I know the integrand has a single pole at  $z=-i/2$ and a double pole at $z=-3i$

My question is for centres $a=3,5,7i$ how do I know if the poles lie inside the circle to enable use of the Cauchy Integral formula, I'm getting confused as there are $i$ terms. Thank you.

Comment: You could calculate the distance from the center to the pole(s).

Comment: hey thanks could you give me an example for the a=3 one

Comment: The distance from $3$ to $-i/2$ would be $|3-(-i/2)|=\sqrt{9+1/4}=\sqrt{37}/2>2$ and from $3$ to $-3i$ would be $|3-(-3i)|=\sqrt{9+9}=\sqrt{18}=3\sqrt{2}>2$

Comment: My teacher wrote for a=3 
• For a = 3, we have $|a − a1|^2=9+1/4=9.25<4^2$ so only the simple pole lies inside but your comment suggest it lies outside?

Comment: Your post says the radius is 2.  Your comment implies the radius is 4.  Which is it?

Comment: in the exam paper it says radius 2, but in the solutions it has 4^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{a \in \braces{3,5,7\ic}}$.

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\oint_{\verts{z - a}\ =\ 2}{\expo{z^{2}} \over
\pars{2z + \ic}\pars{z + 3\ic}^{2}}\,\dd z}} =
{1 \over 2}\expo{a^{2}}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 2}{\expo{z^{2} + 2az} \over
\bracks{z - \pars{-a - \ic/2}}\bracks{z -\pars{-a - 3\ic}}^{\, 2}}\,\dd z
\end{align}

> $\ds{a \in \braces{3,5,7\ic} \implies \verts{-a - {\ic \over 2}} > 2}$ and
>   $\ds{\verts{-a - 3\ic} > 2}$. So, the above integral
>   $\ds{\color{red}{\texttt{vanishes out}}}$.